# How to integrate angular template from Themeforest into Jhipster applications?

Tags: angular, jhipster

I purchased an angular template from Themeforest and I want to integrate it into my Jhipster application. How to integrate the javascript and CSS into Jhipster applications?

Comment: It depends on whether it's based on Bootstrap or not.

Comment: This is the template I purchased https://themeforest.net/item/smarthr-bootstrap-admin-panel-template/21153150

Comment: It's compatible with Bootstrap 4 so it should be fine with JHipster. The link you provided does not show any documentation, so I suppose you must use angular cli to add it as a dependency like any other dependency and/or follow example in your project's README.md

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.