# How to integrate an angular template into a generated jhipster application?

Tags: angular, jhipster

I purchased an angular template from Theme Forest and would like to integrate it into an already generated JHipster application, but can't get it done. The purpose of this is to learn how it works, and later create a blueprint with this template.

Here's the template I purchased: [Dashplex](https://themeforest.net/item/dashplex-angular-admin-dashboard-template/37774906).
It is an Angular 13 / Bootstrap 5 template.

I tried to implement it by putting assets files in a folder created inside src/main/webapp/content directory, but the build fails when I'm doing `./mvnw` and I got those errors:

```
[INFO] ./src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[0]
.oneOf[0].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[0]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[1]!./src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss - Warning: Modul
e Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
[INFO] Warning
[INFO]
[INFO] (2434:3) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] ./src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[0]
.oneOf[0].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[0]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[1]!./src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss - Error: Module 
Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
[INFO] C:\Users\jalfonso\Workspace\tmp\dashplex\src\main\webapp\content\theme_dashplex\scss\bootstrap\_cards.scss:758:2: Can't resolve '../theme_dashplex/scss/img/media/6.jpg' in 'C:\Users\jalfonso\Workspace\tmp\dashplex\src\main\we
bapp\content\scss'
[INFO]
[INFO] ./src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[0]
.oneOf[0].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[0]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[1]!./src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss - Error: Module 
Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
[INFO] C:\Users\jalfonso\Workspace\tmp\dashplex\src\main\webapp\content\theme_dashplex\scss\bootstrap\_cards.scss:763:2: Can't resolve '../theme_dashplex/scss/img/media/8.jpg' in 'C:\Users\jalfonso\Workspace\tmp\dashplex\src\main\we
bapp\content\scss'
[INFO]
[INFO] ./src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[0]
.oneOf[0].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[0]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[1]!./src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss - Error: Module 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:34 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-08T16:42:56+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.1:npm (webapp build dev) on project dashplex: Failed to run task: 'npm run webapp:build' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with a
n error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I also found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69401289/how-to-integrate-angular-template-from-themeforest-into-jhipster-applications) and Gaël Marziou's comment, but I don't know how I could add my template as a dependency?

Comment: Have you contacted their support? You're paying for it. Where is their documentation?

Comment: I got a few files of documentation with the template, but found nothing about how to integrate it. I'll try to contact their support, thanks!